# Compiling results in error "undefined symbols for architecture i386"

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, mono, xamarin.ios

I've compiled the Box2D library in Xcode which has generated a static library file.

I linked this library to mono touch but when I try to compile I get errors about undefined symbols in various source files.

I've looked at the first few and they seem to be complaining about pointer initializations (i.e. using malloc/new), for example:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      b2BroadPhase::b2BroadPhase()in libBox2D.a(b2BroadPhase.o)
      b2BroadPhase::~b2BroadPhase()in libBox2D.a(b2BroadPhase.o)
      b2BroadPhase::~b2BroadPhase()in libBox2D.a(b2BroadPhase.o)
      b2BroadPhase::b2BroadPhase()in libBox2D.a(b2BroadPhase.o)
      b2Island::Solve(b2TimeStep const&, b2Vec2 const&, bool)in libBox2D.a(b2Island.o)
      b2World::b2World(b2Vec2 const&, bool)in libBox2D.a(b2World.o)
      b2World::SolveTOI(b2Body*)     in libBox2D.a(b2World.o)
```

The b2BroadPhase constructor looks like so:

```
b2BroadPhase::b2BroadPhase()
{
    m_proxyCount = 0;

    m_pairCapacity = 16;
    m_pairCount = 0;
    m_pairBuffer = (b2Pair*)b2Alloc(m_pairCapacity * sizeof(b2Pair));

    m_moveCapacity = 16;
    m_moveCount = 0;
    m_moveBuffer = (int32*)b2Alloc(m_moveCapacity * sizeof(int32));
}
```

The b2Alloc function is simple:

```
void* b2Alloc(int32 size)
{
    return malloc(size);
}
```

And commenting out the two lines calling b2Alloc makes the error when the library is linked go away, though obviously that's not a solution to the problem.

I've found other people have had similar problems but all their problems have been with Xcode compiling, I'm not sure how I could fix this issue in mono touch?

edit: In response to Mark Bs answer I'd like to add I'm loading up the lib with the following command line:

```
-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lBox2D -cxx -force_load
${ProjectDir}/libBox2D.a"
```

Which should mean that the lib is loaded up with C++ as per [this documentation](http://ios.xamarin.com/index.php?title=Documentation/Linking_Native_Libraries&highlight=static%20library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a bit confusing but **-cxx** is an extra parameter to **mtouch**, not for --gcc_flags (which are directly passed to **gcc** compiler).

So mtouch extra argument should look like:

```
 -cxx -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lBox2D -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libBox2D.a"
```

**-cxx** will ensure g++ gets used instead of gcc - and that should solve your issue.

Comment: the documentation web page has been updated with an example to avoid confusion about -cxx

Answer (score 3):

Change the .m file to mm, It worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

It sounds at first glance like you're linking as C instead of C++ so it doesn't get the right standard library.

Comment: I just double checked, the argument I'm using to pass in the library is: -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lBox2D -cxx -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libBox2D.a" where from my understanding the -cxx flag ensures it links the lib as C++