# Card.io binding project fails app compilation

Tags: xamarin.ios, card.io

I'm attempting to call Card.IO from my Xamarin app. I get "**Undefined symbols for architecture i386:**" when I try to compile my app and it cites "std::terminate()" in the message. The app is intended for iPhone, I don't know where did the "i386" come from - all settings in project options that I can find are set to ARMv7, so is the LinkWith attribute in the binding.

Card.IO's guide states I need to add `-lstdc++` to "other linker flags" in Xcode but I don't know where should I put this in Xamarin Studio's options

Question is: **how do I make this binding work?** Is there an error in the binding? Is there some project setting or somehow adding more framework references in my app?

I used [Objective Sharpie](http://blog.xamarin.com/introducing-objective-sharpie/) to generate the code below

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit; 

namespace CardIO
{       
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    public partial interface CardIOCreditCardInfo {

        [Export ("cardNumber")]
        string CardNumber { get; set; }

        [Export ("redactedCardNumber")]
        string RedactedCardNumber { get; }

        [Export ("expiryMonth")]
        uint ExpiryMonth { get; set; }

        [Export ("expiryYear")]
        uint ExpiryYear { get; set; }

        [Export ("cvv")]
        string Cvv { get; set; }

        [Export ("zip")]
        string Zip { get; set; }

        [Export ("scanned")]
        bool Scanned { get; set; }

        [Export ("cardType")]
        CardIOCreditCardType CardType { get; }

        [Static, Export ("displayStringForCardType:usingLanguageOrLocale:")]
        string DisplayStringForCardType (CardIOCreditCardType cardType, string languageOrLocale);

        [Static, Export ("logoForCardType:")]
        NSObject LogoForCardType (CardIOCreditCardType cardType);
    } 

    [Model]
    [BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
    public partial interface CardIOPaymentViewControllerDelegate {

        [Export ("userDidCancelPaymentViewController:")]
        void UserDidCancelPaymentViewController (CardIOPaymentViewController paymentViewController);

        [Export ("userDidProvideCreditCardInfo:inPaymentViewController:")]
        void UserDidProvideCreditCardInfo (CardIOCreditCardInfo info, CardIOPaymentViewController paymentViewController);
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (UINavigationController))]
    public partial interface CardIOPaymentViewController {

        [Export ("initWithPaymentDelegate:")]
        IntPtr Constructor (CardIOPaymentViewControllerDelegate aDelegate);

        [Export ("initWithPaymentDelegate:scanningEnabled:")]
        IntPtr Constructor (CardIOPaymentViewControllerDelegate aDelegate, bool scanningEnabled);

        [Export ("appToken")]
        string AppToken { get; set; }

        [Export ("languageOrLocale")]
        string LanguageOrLocale { get; set; }

        [Export ("keepStatusBarStyle")]
        bool KeepStatusBarStyle { get; set; }

        [Export ("navigationBarStyle")]
        UIBarStyle NavigationBarStyle { get; set; }

        [Export ("navigationBarTintColor")]
        UIColor NavigationBarTintColor { get; set; }

        [Export ("disableBlurWhenBackgrounding")]
        bool DisableBlurWhenBackgrounding { get; set; }

        [Export ("collectExpiry")]
        bool CollectExpiry { get; set; }

        [Export ("collectCVV")]
        bool CollectCvv { get; set; }

        [Export ("collectZip")]
        bool CollectZip { get; set; }

        [Export ("showsFirstUseAlert")]
        bool ShowsFirstUseAlert { get; set; }

        [Export ("useCardIOLogo")]
        bool UseCardIolOgo { get; set; }

        [Export ("disableManualEntryButtons")]
        bool DisableManualEntryButtons { get; set; }

        [Export ("paymentDelegate")]
        CardIOPaymentViewControllerDelegate PaymentDelegate { get; set; }

        [Export ("canReadCardWithCamera")]
        bool CanReadCardWithCamera { get; }

        [Export ("libraryVersion")]
        string LibraryVersion { get; }
    } 
}
```

I also added the frameworks listed in Card.IO's site to the .linkswith file:

```cs
[assembly: LinkWith ("libCardIO.a", LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.ArmV7s | LinkTarget.Simulator, ForceLoad = true
, Frameworks="AVFoundation AudioToolbox CoreMedia CoreVideo MobileCoreServices OpenGLES QuartzCore Security UIKit")]
```

Then I added a project reference in my app to the newly created binding project but it doesn't compile. I get this error in Xamarin's output console:

```
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc  -Wl,-no_pie -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk  /Users/Sten/Dropbox/Code/Projects/Tabit/TabitOne_iPhone/TabitOne/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/main.i386.cache.OHBLJlHbpZ74bpnhszg9JrCN8A8=.o -o /var/folders/bb/2tbfzn4n2dq6rsmtpv_jlmbr0000gq/T/tmp59582304.tmp/TabitOne -framework CFNetwork -framework AssetsLibrary -framework Accounts -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework Foundation -framework CoreMotion -framework GameKit -framework GLKit -framework iAd -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework NewsstandKit -framework OpenGLES -framework Social -framework StoreKit -framework Twitter -framework UIKit -framework PassKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework ImageIO -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreVideo -framework ExternalAccessory -framework AdSupport -framework QuickLook -lz -liconv -u _mono_pmip -u _monotouch_create_managed_ref -u _monotouch_release_managed_ref -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr -u _monotouch_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr -u _CloseZStream -u _CreateZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -lmono-2.0 -lmonotouch-debug -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib -u _catch_exception_raise  -force_load /var/folders/bb/2tbfzn4n2dq6rsmtpv_jlmbr0000gq/T/tmp59582304.tmp/libCardIO.a
**Undefined symbols for architecture i386:**
  "**std::terminate()**", referenced from:
      -[CardIOGPURenderer dealloc] in libCardIO.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libCardIO.a(CardIOAnalytics.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libCardIO.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libCardIO.a(CardIOAnimation.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libCardIO.a(CardIOAnalytics.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libCardIO.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libCardIO.a(CardIOAnimation.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libCardIO.a(CardIOAnalytics.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libCardIO.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libCardIO.a(CardIOAnimation.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
```

Comment: FYI, i386 code is bundled to support the iOS simulator. (No camera support, just a fallback manual entry mode)

Comment: @tomwhipple thank you for that bit of info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the answer in another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050509/compiling-results-in-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386) I got this to work by editing my app's project options, page "iOS Build", field "Additional mtouch arguments" where I put the value:

```
-cxx -gcc_flags "-lstdc++"
```